# Any way to fix components variable in Winforms Designer auto-generated code?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-forms-designer, auto-generate

I'm experiencing a very nasty with Winforms Designer auto generated code. Sometimes it creates the ***components*** variable, and sometimes it doesn't. Even if there ARE components on the form that are designed to be used with an IContainer instance, such as `ErrorProvider`.

It seems to happens randomly. In [this MSDN thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8f411138-1b4f-41fc-8ec1-606c69296eb0/designer-generated-code-problem-with-icontainer-components) it is suggested to deactivate "`Optimized Code Generation`" in the designer's options. Unfortunately in my case it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Is anyone else experiencing this? What can be done to ensure that this variable always gets generated when needed?

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party UI controls?

Comment: I do, actually. I'm using DevExpress's. In fact all of my forms are derived from XtraForm one way or another.

Comment: I experienced a similar problem with not DevExpress, but with another less-known library. Maybe you could try removing dependencies to those controls and see if it still occurs. I guess that might be difficult in your situation though.

Comment: I just submitted the issue to support center. I'll see what happens. It's strange that it could be related to 3rd party controls though, given that appearantly some people did reproduced it without ever mentionning using such tools.

Comment: There might be multiple reasons of course. My problem was not exactly the same: the designer file would not save (although it looked like saved), and when I reopened the form my changes would be gone.